# Firebase orderByChild - weird behavior

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to "filter result" results with the following code:

Method 1:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CollaboratorSkillDao.COLLABORATOR_SKILLS_PATH);
ref.orderByChild(CollaboratorSkill.JSON_COLLABORATOR_ID).equalTo(id);
ref.addValueEventListener(new OnDataChange() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
    }
});
```

Method 2:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CollaboratorSkillDao.COLLABORATOR_SKILLS_PATH)            
    .orderByChild(CollaboratorSkill.JSON_COLLABORATOR_ID).equalTo(id)
    .addValueEventListener(new OnDataChange() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        }
     });
```

As far as I know, they are equivalent. 
But for method 1 it returns 58 results and for method 2, 4.

This mean that method 1 ins't filtering.
Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call one of the query methods (`orderBy...`, `equalTo`, etc) it creates a new query object. So you need to capture that in a variable and  use it:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(CollaboratorSkillDao.COLLABORATOR_SKILLS_PATH);
Query query = ref.orderByChild(CollaboratorSkill.JSON_COLLABORATOR_ID).equalTo(id);
query.addValueEventListener(new OnDataChange() {
    ...
```